# How can I see the repository path of a local copy?

Tags: svn

This is probably close to trivial, but I can't find it. How can I see where in the repository a local copy refers to?
Say, I have a workspace checked out some time ago, I want to see if it was checked out from a branch or the trunk.

Comment: // , Would you please add some details about what research you tried before asking?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use

```
svn info
```

Answer (score 3):

For repository root :

Linux : `svn info | grep 'Repository Root' | awk '{print $NF}'`

Windows :  `svn info | findstr /C:"Repository Root: "`

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for a way to find this out programmatically and reliably, this command gives you exactly the repository root, nothing else:

```
svn info --show-item wc-root
```

Comment: // , If this works on multiple platforms the same way, it's a superior answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/30096047/2146138.

Comment: this gives the working-copy root. I think the op wanted the repository url : svn info --show-item url

Answer (score 2):

SVN wasn't available on my laptop, windows crashed and my wifi card wasn't recognized by linux mint when i booted from USB, so I was able to find this in `wc.db` in the top level .svn directory.

Assuming your repo is hosted on an external domain:

```
cat wc.db | grep -a "\.com" | less
```

Should find it.  It is a binary file so it will be ugly, and potentially huge depending on the size of your repo.

Comment: // , This looks like it would work on a dead system as long as you have read access to its persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

I used a tricky way

```
> Open .svn folder
> Open wc.db file with notepad or notepad++.
> Scroll the document and you will find the URL
```

Comment: That is an unencrypted sqlite database, why would you open it in notepad? Select Root from Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Use `svn info`:

```
svn info --show-item url
```

Comment: This would benefit from further explanation, since [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591143/3025856) suggests `svn info`, and [another answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171106/3025856) suggests `--show-item`. The real difference is using `url` instead of `wc-root`. Why is `url` preferred here?